# Encrypted source code neverseen

Tags: php, encryption

Good day! the other day one of my clients sent me a source code from someone else, encrypted in a way I have never encounter before. None of us understands why..

```
\x3c\x21DOCT\x59\x50\x45\x20\x68\x74\x6d\x6c\x20PUB\x4c\x49C 
\x22\x2d\x2f\x2fW\x33\x43\x2f/\x44\x54\x44\x20\x58HTM\x4c\
```

this is a little piece of it, and it keeps on going. From what characters I have managed to put together I can see that it is php and...that's about it...Can anyone please tell me what kind of encryption is this?
Mention: i've searched models on google and came up with no results for my problem.

Comment: It's not ecrypted at all, it was just converted to UTF-8

Comment: -1 for no research effort

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are just UTF-8 character codes. You could parse that out pretty easily:

```
echo htmlentities("\x3c\x21DOCT\x59\x50\x45\x20\x68\x74\x6d\x6c\x20PUB\x4c\x49C\x22\x2d\x2f\x2fW\x33\x43\x2f/\x44\x54\x44\x20\x58HTM\x4c", ENT_QUOTES | ENT_IGNORE, "UTF-8");
```

Output: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD XHTML`

Comment: can you please tell me what should I do to parse them? googled it but cannot understand english that good..